# Text editor same to Stackoverflow for write a code - PHP

Tags: php, html

Hi guys i m building a php website, and in this site i want implemented the tutorial part video+code but when i write a php code in my text area, this code not display. Sow i used the html specialchars into pre, and everything it's okay,

```
<?php

$code = $row['contenuto'] ;

echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($code) . '</pre>';

?>
```

but i have this problem, if i want only write the code it's okay.But text + code nope.
How to implemented a text area same to stack overflow or similar to have the possibilities to write text+code?

Thanks a lot

ADDPAGE:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php

include("../connessione.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['competenze'])) {

$result = mysqli_query($connessione,

"SELECT * FROM amministratore");

?>

<!-- FINE CONTROLLO DELLA SESSIONE -->

<?php include("header-articoli.php");?>

<?php

// IMPLEMENTIAMO LA VARIABILE MESSAGGIO

$messaggio = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include '../../connessione.php';



//REAL_ESCAPE_STRING ANTI STRINGA BUCA DB

$titolo = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['titolo']);

$descrizione = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['descrizione']);

$contenuto = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['contenuto']);


// IMPLEMENTA PASSWORD_HASH PER INNALZAMENTO SICUREZZA PHP VERSION 5.6 MAGGIORE



$connessione->query("INSERT INTO wp (titolo,descrizione,contenuto) VALUES ('$titolo', '$descrizione', '$contenuto')");

$messaggio = "Articolo in Wordpress correttamente inserito!";

}



?>


<div style="text-align: center;padding-top: 0px;" class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<?php if ($messaggio != "")   echo "<img src='../immagini/wordpress.png' style='max-width: 15%;max-height: 15%;'"  . '<br><br><br>' . $messaggio . '<br><br><br>' ; ?>

<form method="post" action="aggiungi-wp.php">

<input class="form-control" minlength="3" name="titolo" placeholder="Titolo"><br>

<textarea name="descrizione" rows="3" cols="40" placeholder="Descrizione" style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid #000;"></textarea>

<textarea  name="contenuto" rows="30" cols="40" placeholder="Contenuto" style="width: 100%;border: 1px solid #000;"></textarea>




<input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Pubblica"><br>

</form>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3"></div>

</div>
</div>

<!-- FINE CONTENUTO SE LA CONDIZIONE E' VERA -->

<?php

}else{ ?>

Contenuto non accesisbile, gentilmente esegui il login per entrare nella tua area privata. Grazie
<!-- FINE CONTENUTO SE LA CONDIZIONE E' FALSA -->

<?php } ?>
```

DISPLAY PAGE:

```
<?php include("header-dettagli.php"); ?>

<?php
session_start();
include_once '../../connessione.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM wp WHERE id='$id'"; $query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
?>
<div style="text-align: ;" class="container"> 
<div class="row"> 

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

<div style="padding-bottom: 30px;" class="col-md-12">
<h3><?php echo $row['titolo'] ;?></h3>
<p><?php echo $row['descrizione'] ;?></p>
</div>


<div class="col-md-12">
<?php

$code = $row['contenuto'] ;

echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($code) . '</pre>';

?>  
</div>


<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us more code, exapmple input, desired output, actual output

Comment: Stack Overflow uses a "markdown editor".